# How to map one to many JPA relationship?

Tags: jpa

I'm getting `Unknown column 'imageprope1_.enid' in 'field list'` with the following mapping:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name="enid", referencedColumnName="pnid")
private List<EntityImageProperty> imageProperties = new ArrayList<>();
```

Here's the key entity mapping:

**BaseEntityProperty**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="enpptpcd",   discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Table(name=BaseEntityProperty.TABLE_NAME)
public abstract class BaseEntityProperty implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name="enppid")
    private String entityPropertyId=null;

    @Column(name="enid")
    private String entityId=null;
```

**EntityImageProperty**

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorValue(EntityImageProperty.DISCRIMINATOR_VALUE)
@Table(name=EntityImageProperty.TABLE_NAME)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="enppid")
public class EntityImageProperty extends BaseEntityProperty {
```

It looks like `@JoinColumn(name="enid", referencedColumnName="pnid")` tells Hibernate to join on `EntityImageProperty.enid`, whereas it should join on `BaseEntityProperty.enid`.

Comment: @JoinColumn has an attribute 'table'.Try specifying the table name of the base class. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#table()

Comment: This requires a secondary table mapping. If I can't find a way to work this out, I may very well remove inheritance mapping shown above.